# Mocking a method to return for some parameters and throws exception for all other parameters

Tags: c#, moq

I am using `Moq` to mock a method:

```
public class DbService : IDbService
{
    public Record GetRecord(Guid Id)
    {
        // Returns the record if exists.
        // Throws exception if record not found.
    }
}
```

I want to mock this such that if I pass these three guids, it returns the records and for *all other Guids* throws an exception.

```
Guid id = Guid.NewGuid();
Guid id2 = Guid.NewGuid();
Guid id3 = Guid.NwGuid();

var mock = new Mock<IDbService>();
mock.Setup(t => t.GetRecord(id)).Returns(record1);
mock.Setup(t => t.GetRecord(id2)).Returns(record2);
mock.Setup(t => t.GetRecord(id3)).Returns(record3);
// Throw exception for all other guids...
```

How can I do this?

Comment: And what is **currently** happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually that was so easy:

```
mock.Setup(t => t.GetRecord(It.IsAny<Guid>())).Throws(new MyException());
mock.Setup(t => t.GetRecord(id)).Returns(record1);
mock.Setup(t => t.GetRecord(id2)).Returns(record2);
mock.Setup(t => t.GetRecord(id3)).Returns(record3);
```

Comment: This is fine, but note that for some values (the three specific GUIDs) you have two `Setup` that match, and in that case the order of your `Setup` calls becomes important. Which is why you put the `It.IsAny<Guid>()` line first, not last. If you do not want dependency on the order of `Setup`, prefer Maor Veitsman's solution (other answer). It can also be written `.Setup(t => t.GetRecord(It.Is((Guid q) => q != id && q != id2 && q != id3)))` if you prefer. If you have many in a list (or set), `.Setup(t => t.GetRecord(It.Is((Guid q) => !yourList.Contains(q))))`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `MockBehavior.Strict` for this:

```
Guid id = Guid.NewGuid();
Guid id2 = Guid.NewGuid();
Guid id3 = Guid.NwGuid();

var mock = new Mock<IDbService>(MockBehavior.Strict);

mock.Setup(t => t.GetRecord(id)).Returns(record1);
mock.Setup(t => t.GetRecord(id2)).Returns(record2);
mock.Setup(t => t.GetRecord(id3)).Returns(record3);

// do stuff

// will throw if GetRecord was called with arguments
// that don't match to any configured setup.
mock.VerifyAll();
```

Comment: It's not exactly the same, here Moq will throw its own exception, in the accepted answer the service itself will throw its exception (the one expected)

Answer (score 4):

The following code should do the trick:

```
mock.Setup(t => t.GetRecord(It.Is<Guid>(q => q != id && q != id2 && q != id3)))
.Throws(new Exception("Bad Guid"));
```